# PHP filter 2 dimensional array by specific key

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, filtering

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [702a4584] => Array
        (
            [type] => folder
            [id] => 702a4584
        )

    [b547b3a9] => Array
        (
            [type] => folder
            [id] => b547b3a9

        )

    [fcb0d055] => Array
        (
            [type] => page
            [id] => fcb0d055
        )
)
```

I want to filter the array such that only type "folder" will remain:

```
Array
(
    [702a4584] => Array
        (
            [type] => folder
            [id] => 702a4584
        )

    [b547b3a9] => Array
        (
            [type] => folder
            [id] => b547b3a9

        )

)
```

I could do this, but I'll be needing a generic function:

```
$temp = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    if($value['type'] =="folder")
    {
        $temp[$key] = $value; 
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "generic function" ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter):

```
$filtered = array_filter($array, function($v) { return $v['type'] == 'folder'; });
```

Comment: That should be `return $v['type'] == 'folder';`.

Comment: @fireeyedboy: oops, good catch, fixed. I was thinking for some reason he wanted just pages :)

Comment: how to count the number of different type in the above associative array?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a strange situation that might be useful to add here for someone in the future, since when I was searching for it, it pointed to this post.

I´m using Laravel and when I dumped `@dump($myData)` my 2 dimensional array, it was showing as array inside arrays. However, my filter_array logic wasn´t working.

After hours trying to debug it, I used old school `var_dump($myData)` and found out that the inner array wasnt´s an array - it had been converted for some reason into an object. And it was returning me the following error:
`Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`.

Struggled a a bit more until I came up with two alternatives:

**Assume the object:**

```php
$filteredArray = array_filter($originalArray, function ($arr) {
    return $arr->id_filter_index === 101; // Working. For some reason, the $arr is an object.
});
```

**Force array conversion:**

```php
$filteredArray = array_filter($originalArray, function ($arr) {
    $arr = json_decode(json_encode($arr), true); // Force converting to array.
    return $arr['id_filter_index'] === 101;
});
```

BTW: the `$originalArray` was filtered also and not sure why the inner arrays became objects. If anyone has context about it, leave it in the comments. Hope this saves valuable debugging time for anyone out there.

Answer (score -1):

```
$input = Array(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6);
$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $input)));
```

Comment: The question is how to filter 2-dimensional array by a specific key value but your answer is a solution of how to remove duplicated elements in a simple array.