# Filter a 2d array to only keep rows where a specific column value is greater than nominated value

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, array-filter

I have a form that submits the following data.  I only want to select the data with QTY of 1 or more.

```
array (size=4)
  17 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '17' (length=2)
      'TicketName' => string 'General admission' (length=17)
      'price' => string '50.00' (length=5)
      'qty' => string '0' (length=1)
  18 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '18' (length=2)
      'TicketName' => string 'General admission' (length=17)
      'price' => string '50.00' (length=5)
      'qty' => string '2' (length=1)
  19 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '19' (length=2)
      'TicketName' => string 'General admission' (length=17)
      'price' => string '50.00' (length=5)
      'qty' => string '0' (length=1)
  20 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '20' (length=2)
      'TicketName' => string 'General admission' (length=17)
      'price' => string '50.00' (length=5)
      'qty' => string '0' (length=1)
```

I know I can use something like.  I'm not sure how to filter by the qty key.

```
$arrays = array_filter($inputs, function($val) {
                return $val > 0;
          });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filter multidimensional arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681245/filter-multidimensional-arrays)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each element of your array `$input`, is an array. So you need to access the value associated to the key `qty`:

```
$arrays = array_filter($inputs, function($elem){
    return (int)$elem['qty'] > 0;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I run this code i'm getting a "Illegal string offset 'qty'" error

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array();    
foreach($main_array as $chunk){
  if($chunk['qty'] > 0 ){
    $array[] = $chunk;
  }
}
var_dump($array);
```