# Remove empty elements of array with some rules

Tags: php, arrays

I have problem with remove empty arrays.
My array looks like:

```
Array
(
    [Women] => Array
        (
            [S] => Array
                (
                    [warehouse] => 22
                    [price] => 21212
                )

            [M] => Array
                (
                    [warehouse] => 
                    [price] => 
                )

            [L] => Array
                (
                    [warehouse] => 
                    [price] => 
                )

            [XL] => Array
                (
                    [warehouse] => 
                    [price] => 
                )

            [XXL] => Array
                (
                    [warehouse] => 
                    [price] => 
                )

        )
    [Men] => Array
        (
            [S] => Array
                (
                    [warehouse] => 22
                    [price] => 
                )

            [M] => Array
                (
                    [warehouse] => 
                    [price] => 
                )

            [L] => Array
                (
                    [warehouse] => 
                    [price] => 
                )

            [XL] => Array
                (
                    [warehouse] => 
                    [price] => 
                )

            [XXL] => Array
                (
                    [warehouse] => 
                    [price] => 
                )

        )
)
```

Last child always have two keys ( warehouse and price )

My code:

```
$value = $this->$attribute;   
$check = function($haystack) use(&$check)
{
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $haystack[$key] = $check($haystack[$key]);
        }

        if (empty($haystack[$key])) {
            unset($haystack[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $haystack;
};

var_dump(  $check($value) );
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [Women] => Array
        (
            [S] => Array
                (
                    [warehouse] => 22
                    [price] => 21212
                )

        )

    [Men] => Array
        (
            [S] => Array
                (
                    [warehouse] => 22
                )

        )
)
```

Its working but my problem is that the 'Men array' should be remove because last level have only warehouse key ( Correct two keys ).
How change my function to get result who i want?

Comment: Use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) - see [Multidimensional array element if empty delete entire sub-array PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35490098/multidimensional-array-element-if-empty-delete-entire-sub-array-php#35495083)

Comment: Need a more explanation about the code, what is $haystack containing

Answer (score 0):

if $array is containing this
`

```
Array
(
    [Women] => Array
        (
            [S] => Array
                (
                    [warehouse] => 22
                    [price] => 21212
                )
        [M] => Array
            (
                [warehouse] => 
                [price] => 
            )

        [L] => Array
            (
                [warehouse] => 
                [price] => 
            )

        [XL] => Array
            (
                [warehouse] => 
                [price] => 
            )

        [XXL] => Array
            (
                [warehouse] => 
                [price] => 
            )

    )
[Men] => Array
    (
        [S] => Array
            (
                [warehouse] => 22
                [price] => 
            )

        [M] => Array
            (
                [warehouse] => 
                [price] => 
            )

        [L] => Array
            (
                [warehouse] => 
                [price] => 
            )

        [XL] => Array
            (
                [warehouse] => 
                [price] => 
            )

        [XXL] => Array
            (
                [warehouse] => 
                [price] => 
            )
      )
)
```

Then iterate each array key women, men in each of that key we will iterate to s,m,l,xl if any of the prize has missing elements we will unset it, and at last of iteration we will check the size of women and men, if one of them dont have size then we will unset the gender key.

```
foreach($array as $gender => $array_val){
  foreach($gender as $size=>$size_val){
    if(empty($size_val)){
      unset($array[$gender][$size]);
    }
  }
  if(count($array[$gender])==0) unset($array[$gender]);
}
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: I think you don't understand me. If last parent both params (warehouse and price) is empty then array must be unset

Comment: Sorry,the array sized [s] on men is removed then?