# How to use an array as data base?

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
    $travels = [
    0 => ['departure' => 'Paris', 'arrival' => 'Nantes'],
    1 => ['departure' => 'Orleans', 'arrival' => 'Nantes'],
    2 => ['departure' => 'Dublin', 'arrival' => 'Tours'],
    3 => ['departure' => 'Paris', 'arrival' => 'Orleans'],
    4 => ['departure' => 'Paris', 'arrival' => 'Nice'],
    5 => ['departure' => 'Nice', 'arrival' => 'Nantes'],
    6 => ['departure' => 'Nice', 'arrival' => 'Tours'],
    7 => ['departure' => 'Tours', 'arrival' => 'Amboise'],
    8 => ['departure' => 'Nice', 'arrival' => 'Nantes'],
];
```

So this is my code, I want to use this multiple array as a data base, but there is no queries right?

So, I simply want to get all the arrivals values from one departure, like all the arrivals starting from paris, i've tried many things with foreach loop inside foreachloop and if statments and to use the index array but no chance. Is there any way to do it like a query in mysql.

Would be something like:

```
"SELECT 'arrival' FROM 'travels' WHERE 'departure' = Paris"
```

Comment: You've already tried a foreach loop; could you include that? Also, where is this array coming from originally?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP filter 2 dimensional array by specific key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341033/php-filter-2-dimensional-array-by-specific-key)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understood your question, you could do something like this:

```
$resultArr = [];

array_walk($travels, function($value, $key) use (&$resultArr) {
    if($value['departure'] == 'Paris')
       $resultArr[$key] = $value;
});
```

This will fill your new array with those departures, that are only from Paris.

Another approach would be the use of [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.array-filter.php) as suggested by mfonda in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7341049/4807311) of a post:

```
$filtered = array_filter($travels, function($v) { return $v['departure'] == 'Paris'; });
```

Comment: Thx for the response, actually I've used something like that, I've used the if statement but after a foreach loop instead of array_walk thx for the help

Answer (score 0):

This will get all arrivals with departure 'Paris':

```
<?php
$travels = [
  0 => ['departure' => 'Paris', 'arrival' => 'Nantes'],
  1 => ['departure' => 'Orleans', 'arrival' => 'Nantes'],
  2 => ['departure' => 'Dublin', 'arrival' => 'Tours'],
  3 => ['departure' => 'Paris', 'arrival' => 'Orleans'],
  4 => ['departure' => 'Paris', 'arrival' => 'Nice'],
  5 => ['departure' => 'Nice', 'arrival' => 'Nantes'],
  6 => ['departure' => 'Nice', 'arrival' => 'Tours'],
  7 => ['departure' => 'Tours', 'arrival' => 'Amboise'],
  8 => ['departure' => 'Nice', 'arrival' => 'Nantes'],
];
foreach ($travels as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['departure'] == 'Paris') {
        echo $value['arrival'];
}
}
?>
```

This will list all the arrivals, however, if you want to limit to only show the arrival name once, you'll have to add some code.

Comment: You should use one foreach loop.

Comment: This worked like a charm, in fact I've had already discovered that , first time I used the if statement I did a basic mistake of making the equal sign one time lol I was getting frustrated , but as always in the end it always works thx!!

Comment: @BunkerBoy how exactly will a "double foreach not work in this case"?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie sorry i my bad, but use of 2nd foreach() has no sense

Comment: Agreed, hence I removed the inner foreach from my answer.